# Angular, http request with header and token for a login form

Tags: angular, http

I am trying to create a login form in Angular 6. My test app check the data written from the current user and try to match with the data received from a remote service via http. This is the point: with a simple request as following, all works correctly. But what about a request also with header and token?

How can I create a function with this information? Or, do you have a link with a specific tutorial for this case?

```
onlogin(): void {

.get('myLink'=;
.subscribe(data => {
    this.data = data;
    this.loading = false});
}

(....)
```

(example from official Angular 6 Book, page 157)

Comment: Are you trying to do a HTTP Request with few headers and a token?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: Exactly! Thank you very much for the very quick response, I appreciate because is urgent... Do you have an idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular sending token with get (and other) requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48017603/angular-sending-token-with-get-and-other-requests)

Comment: Thank you too CodingFreak, not exactly a duplicate I think... And also in that guide I see several example but I don't understand which part is useful for my case. Thank very much both, I try to edit the question to be more specific. If you can simply explain me how to modify this request to include an header and a token, I appreciate too much! PS Sorry if the question is banal but I am relatively new to Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding a token to the Http request, you can use `RequestOptionsArgs`

```
onlogin(): void {
   let headers = new Headers({ 'authToken':'Place your Token Here' });            
   let reqOptionsArgs  = new RequestOptions({headers:headers});  

 // Your Injected Http in the service.
 this.http
   .get('Your API URL', reqOptionsArgs)
   .subscribe(data => {
      this.data = data;
      this.loading = false});
    });
}
```